# Out of (2n+1) tickets consecutively numbered, three are drawn at random. Find the chance that the numbers on them are in A.P

Tags: probability

Can someone please explain this question and suggest an understandable solution??

Comment: Rhithik, I have added a self-study tag as this question is obviously a study question. It would be useful if you would add more information about the point where you get stuck in this question (or in general in these type of questions).

Comment: Thank you @sextusempiricus but I've solved the question.

Comment: Number the tickets $1,2,\ldots, 2n+1.$ Given $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le n,$ let $d=\min(i,j)$ and $k=n+1+j-i-d.$ You can check that $(k,k+d,k+2d)$ is an arithmetic progression with values between $1$ and $2n+1$ and that $(k,d)$ uniquely determines $(i,j).$  Thus the number of such a.p.'s is $n^2$ and the chance of observing one must be $n^2/\binom{2n+1}{3}=3n/(4n^2-1).$

Answer (score 1):

If this problem relates to the many examples of it that you can find with a search on the internet then A.P. seems to mean [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

- How many ways are there to have an arithmetic progression?

  Hints:

  - Think of the ways to have three consecutive numbers with no space in between, e.g. $k+0,k+1,k+2$. The value of $k$ can have values from $k=1$ till $k=2n-1$.
  - Think of the ways to have three consecutive numbers with $n$ space in between. e.g. k+0, k+n, k+2n. The value of $k$ can be only $k=1$.
  - Think of the possibilities in between and find a formula to express the number of ways to have the arithmetic progressions as function of the space. Then sum all possibilities.
- How many way are there to have three numbers?